# Add elements in a list Python

Tags: python, list, addition

```
under__list =[[74, 0.1423287845938018, None, None, 10, 
   1.9099604642265018, 0.5185563065935468, 1.6825659992347914, 
   3.547506695574544, 2.7789822726693023, 20051, 0, 25, None, ' >50K'],
  [44, 0.9181229773462783, None, None, 14, 0.17973300970873787, 
   0.1644822006472492, 0.13940129449838187, 1.1252427184466018, 
   0.4357200647249191, 0, 0, 40, None, ' <=50K']]
```

I have the above list but I want to add the elements together but skip past the `None` and the `">=50"` elements.

I want to be able to do it even if I don't know where `None` number values are.
Any suggestions?

```
for item in zip(under__list[row]):
    under__list.append(int(sum(item[0])))
```

Looking for the below output:

```
[1182, 25.2452245, None, None, 9212, 256, 2624, 25.24,
   2532, 25, 2005252, 52, 25632, None, ' >50K']
```

It would be one list with numbers added together.

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output for this input; in particular, it isn't clear what `add`ing you wish to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to sum the items on the same indices from all inner lists. For that first of all you need to use `zip` with `*`, and then in the list comprehension check of the first item of each row is an instance of `Number` type or simply `int` or  `float`(`isinstance(x[0], (int, float))`), if yes, sum them else use the first items as value.

```
>>> from numbers import Number
>>> [sum(x) if isinstance(x[0], Number) else x[0] for x in zip(*under__list)]
[118, 1.0604517619400802, None, None, 24, 2.0896934739352395, 0.683038507240796, 1.8219672937331732, 4.672749414021146, 3.2147023373942214, 20051, 0, 65, None, ' >50K']
```

The expression `sum(x) if isinstance(x[0], Number) else x[0]` is called a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in under_list:
    item_ = filter(lambda x: x != None and x >= 50, under_list)
    # Here compute sum of item_ and append to the right place
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to return what you need:

```
def foo(thing):
    try:
        return sum(thing)
    except TypeError:
        return thing[0]
```

`map` the function to the `zip`ped *rows* of `under__list`

```
>>> under__list =[[74, 0.1423287845938018, None, None, 10, 1.9099604642265018, 0.5185563065935468, 1.6825659992347914, 3.547506695574544, 2.7789822726693023, 20051, 0, 25, None,' >50K'], [44, 0.9181229773462783, None, None, 14, 0.17973300970873787, 0.1644822006472492, 0.13940129449838187, 1.1252427184466018, 0.4357200647249191, 0, 0, 40, None, ' <=50K']]

>>> map(foo, zip(*under__list))
[118, 1.0604517619400802, None, None, 24, 2.0896934739352395, 0.683038507240796, 1.8219672937331732, 4.672749414021146, 3.2147023373942214, 20051, 0, 65, None, ' >50K']
>>>
```